# Calculate mean of large numpy array which is memmapped from hdf5 file

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I've a problem with calculating the mean of an array in numpy that is too large for RAM (~100G).

---

I've looked into using `np.memmap`, but unfortunately my array is stored as a dataset in a hdf5 file. And based on what I've tried, np.memmap doesn't accept hdf5 datasets as input.
`TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Dataset found`

So how can I call `np.mean` on a memory mapped array from disk in an efficient way? Of course I could loop over parts of the dataset, where each part fits into the memory.
However, this feels too much like a workaround and I'm also not sure if it would achieve the best performance.

---

Here's some sample code:

```
data = np.randint(0, 255, 100000*10*10*10, dtype=np.uint8)
data.reshape((100000,10,10,10)) # typically lot larger, ~100G

hdf5_file = h5py.File('data.h5', 'w')
hdf5_file.create_dataset('x', data=data, dtype='uint8')

def get_mean_image(filepath):
    """
    Returns the mean_array of a dataset.
    """
    f = h5py.File(filepath, "r")
    xs_mean = np.mean(f['x'], axis=0) # memory error with large enough array

    return xs_mean

xs_mean = get_mean_image('./data.h5')
```

Comment: I'd go ahead an do the chunked read of the `h5py` dataset.  Get that working.  Then you can test whether the iteration is really costing you time.  With large arrays, the costs of memory management can outweigh the costs of iteration.

Comment: You're right, it's actually not costing so much. The only hazzle is the loop that you have to code, so it's not so elegant. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hpaulj suggested in the comments, I've just split the mean calculation into multiple steps.
Here's my (simplified) code if it may be useful for someone:

```
def get_mean_image(filepath):
    """
    Returns the mean_image of a xs dataset.
    :param str filepath: Filepath of the data upon which the mean_image should be calculated.
    :return: ndarray xs_mean: mean_image of the x dataset. 
    """
    f = h5py.File(filepath, "r")

    # check available memory and divide the mean calculation in steps
    total_memory = 0.5 * psutil.virtual_memory() # In bytes. Take 1/2 of what is available, just to make sure.
    filesize = os.path.getsize(filepath)
    steps = int(np.ceil(filesize/total_memory))
    n_rows = f['x'].shape[0]
    stepsize = int(n_rows / float(steps))

    xs_mean_arr = None
    for i in xrange(steps):
        if xs_mean_arr is None: # create xs_mean_arr that stores intermediate mean_temp results
            xs_mean_arr = np.zeros((steps, ) + f['x'].shape[1:], dtype=np.float64)

        if i == steps-1: # for the last step, calculate mean till the end of the file
            xs_mean_temp = np.mean(f['x'][i * stepsize: n_rows], axis=0, dtype=np.float64)
        else:
            xs_mean_temp = np.mean(f['x'][i*stepsize : (i+1) * stepsize], axis=0, dtype=np.float64)
        xs_mean_arr[i] = xs_mean_temp

    xs_mean = np.mean(xs_mean_arr, axis=0, dtype=np.float64).astype(np.float32)

    return xs_mean
```

Comment: The mean of the means is only equal to the true mean if all buckets are the same size. Your last bucket isn't, so it skews your results slightly.

Answer (score 0):

A better mean calculation algorithm would be:

```
N = x.shape[0]
batch_size = 32
num_steps = math.ceil(N / batch_size)

mean = np.zeros(x.shape[1:])

for i in range(num_steps):
    x_batch = x[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size]
    curr_batch_size = x_batch.shape[0]
    mean += x_batch.mean(0) * curr_batch_size / N
          # x_batch.sum(0) / N, alternatively
```

Basically, `(a_1 + a_2 + . . . + a_N) / N = a_1 / N + a_2 / N + . . . + a_N / N`.

This is more precise than computing mean of means (which gives a slightly wrong result when last batch is of a different size), and also doesn't have the memory overhead of storing the means of chunks, as all you're doing is a running sum reduction.